# jQuery change dropdown value and disable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

**Dropdown One:**

```
<select id="parent_task" name="parent_task" class="form-control input-large">
    <option data-task-hours="100" data-parent="0" data-task-category="2444" value="527"> - Requirement Analysis</option>
    <option data-task-hours="100" data-parent="0" data-task-category="2391" value="531"> - Development </option>
    <option data-task-hours="0" data-parent="0" data-task-category="2395" value="535"> - Miscellaneous </option>
</select>
```

**Dropdown Two:**

```
PHP Code

<select name="task_category" id="task_category">
   <option value="">Please select</option>
   <?php foreach ($task_cat_arr as $cat_row) { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $cat_row['CODEID'] ?>"><?php echo $cat_row['DESCRIPTION'] ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>

Outputs:

<select id="task_category" name="task_category">
   <option value="">Please select</option>
   <option value="2444">Bug Fixing & Sustenance</option>
   <option value="2391">Configuration Management</option>
   <option value="2395">Database</option>
</select>
```

When user selects `Requiremnet Analysis` from `parent_task` dropdown, how to select `Bug Fixing & Sustenance` option from `task_category` dropdown and make it `selected` and `disabled`.

It has `data-task-category=2444` associated with it which is the same id for `task_category` dropdown.

How can I achieve this using jQuery ?

Comment: do you want to disable the option or the select?

Comment: disable option and make it selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //change event handler for the parent
    $('#parent_task').change(function () {
        //$(this).find('option:selected')  - finds the selected option element
        //then its data attribute is read and that is set as teh value of the task category
        $('#task_category').val($(this).find('option:selected').data('taskCategory')).prop('disabled', true)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/um2ub6c7/)

Comment: Arun: Could you differentiate between `data('task-category')` and `data('taskCategory')`. Guess it works for both but what's the core difference ? Can I use the former or should I use the latter ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy that is the html5 data api style, where the first char after the `-` is upper cased(except for the `data-`) part

Comment: Arun: I know aboutthe data attribute. Curious to know which one is a better option to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#parent_task').on('change',function(){
    if($('#parent_task option:selected').val()=="527")
    {
        $('#task_category').val("2444");
        $('#task_category').attr('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

Comment: i would use `$('#task_category').prop('disabled',true);` instead

Comment: Not really. It's simply clearer. Because disabled is a property and not an attribute.

Comment: I searched on it , even i got to know that it is a property not an attribute. So its better to use .prop().thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#parent_task').on('change', function(event) {
        if ($(this).val() === "527") {
            var taskCategory = $(this).find(':selected').data('task-category');
            $("#task_category").val(taskCategory).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $("#task_category").prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/troythompson/rbbenefr/